# Please show me a better way to write this code with similiar values in access vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Access code that populate a web form.  Some of my fields have similar names.  What I am trying to do is consolidate them so I'm not repetitive in copying and pasting the code. The following examples are "Action" fields with 5 options:

```
Dim Action1, Action2, Action3, Action4 As Integer

Action1 =  IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "buy", 1, _
           IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "sell", 2, _
           IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "trade", 3, _
           IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "hold", 4, _
           IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "Other", 5, 0)))))

Action2 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "other", 5, 0)))))

Action3 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "Other", 5, 0)))))

Action4 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "other", 5, 0)))))

'Add Action 1 to Web Form
IE.Document.All("txtAction").Value = Action1
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")

If Action1 = 5 Then
    IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
    IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth1
End If

IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")

'Add Action 2 to Web Form
IE.Document.All("txtAction").Value = Action2
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")

If Action2 = 5 Then
    IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
    IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth1
End If

IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can save some of the copy/paste 'volume' by adding a couple helper methods.  Maybe something like this could be helpful:

```
Sub ModifiedExampleWithHelpers()

    AddAction GetAction(Me.cbo_Action1.Value), ActionOth1
    AddAction GetAction(Me.cbo_Action2.Value), ActionOth2
    AddAction GetAction(Me.cbo_Action3.Value), ActionOth3
    AddAction GetAction(Me.cbo_Action4.Value), ActionOth4

End Sub

Private Function GetAction(selection As String) As Integer
    Select Case selection
        Case "buy"
            GetAction = 1
        Case "sell"
            GetAction = 2
        Case "trade"
            GetAction = 3
        Case "hold"
            GetAction = 4
        Case "other"
            GetAction = 5
        Case Else
            GetAction = 0
    End Select
End Function

'Assumes ActionOth1 is an Integer
Private Sub AddAction(action As Integer, actionOth As Integer)

    IE.Document.All("txtAction").Value = action
    IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")

    If action = 5 Then
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = actionOth
    End If

    IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for. I have other fields that have between 16 to 20 options to choose from. This will definitely save me some time. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Edited to make adding an action a single line - 50% less copy/paste lines than the initial answer. :)

Comment: I tried out the code. Made a change to define ActionOth as String and I get an compile error:  ByRef argument type mismatch. The field is a string where user have to input when they select "other" as an option.

Comment: <code>    Private Sub AddAction(Action As Integer, actionOth As String, Outcome As String)

    IE.Document.All("txtAction").Value = Action
    IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")

    If Action = 18 Then
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = actionOth
    End If
    IE.Document.All("txtOutcome").Value = Outcome
    IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick") </code>

Comment: If "IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = actionOth" requires an integer, then CInt(actionOth) might work...if actionOth can be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to have to play with it some more.  The getAction is not working for me.  Not sure what I am doing wrong but while my original code is redundant, it works when I execute the onclick procedure to transfer the data from Access to the Web form.

`Dim Action1, Action2, Action3, Action4 As Integer
Dim ActionOth1, ActionOth2, ActionOth3, ActionOth4 As String
Dim Outcome1, Outcome2, Outcome3, Outcome4 As String`

```
Action1 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action1 = "Other", 5, 0)))))
Action2 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action2 = "other", 5, 0)))))
Action3 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action3 = "Other", 5, 0)))))
Action4 = IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "buy", 1, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "sell", 2, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "trade", 3, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "hold", 4, _
          IIf(Me.cbo_Action4 = "other", 5, 0)))))

IE.Document.All("ddlAction").Value = Action1
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
If Action1 = 5 Then
IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth1
End If
IE.Document.All("txtOutcome").Value = Outcome1
IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

If Action2 > 0 Then
    IE.Document.All("ddlAction").Value = Action2
    IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")
    If Action2 = 5 Then
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth2
    End If
IE.Document.All("txtOutcome").Value = Outcome2
IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")
End If

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

If Action3 > 0 Then
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").Value = Action3
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")
    If Action3 = 5 Then
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth3
    End If
IE.Document.All("txtOutcome").Value = Outcome3
IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")
End If

Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

If Action4 > 0 Then
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").Value = Action4
IE.Document.All("ddlAction").FireEvent ("onchange")
    If Action4 = 5 Then
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Focus
        IE.Document.All("txtOther").Value = ActionOth4
    End If
IE.Document.All("txtOutcome").Value = Outcome4
IE.Document.All("btnactionsubmit").FireEvent ("onclick")
End If
```